# Wrap axios and access redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I want to wrap axios in a utility function so that I can add the base url and auth token which is saved in redux's state

What is the simplest way to do this?

```
    export function qapi(){
    return axios.create({
      baseURL:  ${ROOT_URL} ,
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.props.auth_token}`}
    });
   }
   }
```

How do I now connect this to redux so that I could access the state and props?

Comment: There are ways to do that, but I gotta ask why would you want that data in the state?

Comment: Agree with @MotiAzu that is a bit strange to keep this data in the state.  Are you using Webpack?  If so I can propose an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes I'm using webpack. sure, if you have a better way of doing this, I'm all ears

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to no longer put the auth token in the state but in a cookie instead using react-cookie

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from 'config';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';
import _ from 'lodash';


export function qapi(){
    const ROOT_URL = config.api_url;
    const auth_token = cookie.load('auth_token');
    return axios.create({
          baseURL:  `${ROOT_URL}`,
          timeout: 5000,
          headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`}
        });
}
```